# Responsively change text of <button> element

Tags: html, css

I was wondering if it is possible through css to change the text of a button when the screen size is lower than 400px for example. Now I have something like `<button>Next</button>` and I want to change it to `<button>-></button>`. Is that possible?

Comment: I think if you apply a class to that button, let's call it "change-text", and you specify its style only within the media query you are interested in, it should do the trick, assuming you are using media queries.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

HTML

```
<button id="button-one" name="button">NEXT</button>
<button id="button-two" name="button">-&gt;</button>
```

CSS

```
#button-two { display: none; }

@media (max-width: 400px) {
    #button-one { display: none; }
    #button-two { display: inline; }
}
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/ujag5eya/1/

Answer (score 1):

Another alternate way is to use css `content` an example being

**HTML**

```
<button id="button-one" name="button"></button>
```

**CSS**

```
#button-one::after{
  content:"NEXT"
}
@media (max-width: 400px) {
  #button-one::after{
    content:"->"
  }
}
```

**Codepen**
http://codepen.io/noobskie/pen/ojgOWB

Here's a article by Chris Coyier who explains it well

https://css-tricks.com/swapping-out-text-five-different-ways/

Comment: Often not recommended for accessibility reasons.

Comment: Agreed its nice to know alternatives as well though